# Concatenation plus Joining a table

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have a table with columns pest1, pest2, pest3, ...., pest12. Query below calculates sum of each column
I have made checkboxes for each column in c#. What i want is what ever the user selects the option the query should run accordingly.

for e.g user checks pest1 and pest2 query should look like

```
string sql = "SELECT ";
if (checkBox1.Checked) sql += "SUM(pestpopulation1) as pestpopulation1, ";

if (checkBox2.Checked) sql += "SUM(pestpopulation2) as pestpopulation2, ";

sql += "'' as dummy"; 

sql += " FROM transformed_table;";
```

I have another table with Person Name And Father Name in it  How will i join the two tables in to the same query if user checks Person Name or FatherName

Answer (score 1):

First of all, try to avoid dynamic query.

To obtain your result, you can pass the "checked" value as a `BIT` parameter.

So, assume having such table:

```
CREATE TABLE T (
P1 int,
P2 int,
P3 int
)
```

Use a parametrized query, where you pass 0/1 if the respective checkbox is checked/unchecked:

```
SELECT 
CASE @par1 WHEN 1 THEN SUM(P1) ELSE 0 END P1Sum,
CASE @par2 WHEN 1 THEN SUM(P2) ELSE 0 END P2Sum,
CASE @par3 WHEN 1 THEN SUM(P3) ELSE 0 END P3Sum
```

You would always get a complete row in return, where the unrequested sum are set to 0.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do with Person Name and Father Name? Are you filtering the data based on criteria that the user might enter for those fields?

I'm making some assumptions about what your functionality is with the example below.

```
select ....
from transformed_table tt
left outer join other_table ot on
    (@PersonName is not null or @FatherName is not null)
    and tt.key = ot.key
where
    (@PersonName is null or ot.PersonName = @PersonName)
    and (@FatherName is null or ot.FatherName = @FatherName)
```

If the Person Name checkbox is not checked, then pass in null for the @PersonName parameter, otherwise pass in your criteria. Same goes for the Father Name checkbox and the @FatherName parameter.

I'm assuming that you are trying to let the user optionally filter by either the Person Name or the Father Name (or both). Of course, you can also use more lenient conditions in the where clause, such as the like operator instead of equals.